# Java Apache beam - Side input issue

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

We are streaming the dataflow with FixedWindow of 5 mins. We are using this 5 mins windowed data to query Google Spanner Database and based on the resultset we need to insert to another table in Spanner.

So along with this result set and input from the streaming dataflow we need to insert to another table

So we are creating a View from the resultset and pass this view as a side input to the next step.

In the next step along with this side input, we will do some processing and insert the data to the database

We are using SpannerIO to read data from the database.

Suppose if there is no data in side input(data not present in the database) the next step is not getting executed even though the main input has data.

But in this case as well we need to insert the data to the database. Due to this side input issue, dataflow pipeline is halting.

Comment: How is your side input getting generated? Is it also windowed? Typically the next step should get executed once the side input's watermark advances sufficiently, regardless of whether it has data in it.

Comment: all the steps are executed beneath the window function, even sometimes we can see the sideinput with null values, but the Pcollection used to populate this sideinput has value in it, even though the side input is getting null value.